# Remote deploy from Eclipse to JBoss AS and integration Eclipse with remote JBoss

Tags: eclipse, deployment, jboss

I have the following situation. My JBoss server runs on the remote server under some bound address. I would like to run Eclipse on my local machine and deploy results of work to the remote server where I could test it and debug it. I'm working on enterprise Java project and I'm normally deploying one ear file. 
I know how to provide remote debugging but what possibilities exist for integrating remove deploy in Eclipse?

I was trying for first the JBoss tools plugin. There is a deploy-only server for the only deploying the project. I'm connected on the network disk on the remote server where JBoss instance runs. 
But this plugin deploys ear exploded and afterwards because of the one persistence.xml in my project where tag  defines what jars contain entities and instead of the jar there are something.jar directories. Then hibernate isn't able to load entities.

Is there some possibility how to easily make a remote deploy directly from Eclipse? Or better is there possibility how to integrate work on remote JBoss server in Eclipse (I mean run JBoss server, stop it.)?